# Disable selected option of the first select box in the second select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I want to find student's data by inserting their subject name and their score range. The teacher can add a new subject with an add button and can remove the subject too. Also the subject/option that has been already selected in the previous row will disable in the next new row.

1. Here is the html code

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-bricky btn-sm" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Delete Row</button>

<table id="dataTable" class="table table-striped"  style="font-size: 12px" >
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk"/></td>
    <td>
        <select name="subject" id="subject">
                          <option value="Math">Math</option>
                          <option value="Physic">Physic</option>
                          <option value="Chemistry">Chemistry</option>
                          <option value="Biology">Biology</option>
                </select>
Score Min : <input type="number" name="comsMin" style="width:70px" min="0" max="100"/>
Max :  <input type="number" name="comsMax" style="width:70px" min="0" max="100"/></td>

</tr>
</table>
```

And here is the JavaScript code

```
function addRow(tableID) {

            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

            var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

            for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

                var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

                newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
                //alert(newcell.childNodes);
                switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                    case "#text":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                            break;
                    case "#checkbox":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                            break;
                    case "#select-one":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                            break;
                }
            }
        }
//--------------
        function deleteRow(tableID) {
            try {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;

            for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
                var row = table.rows[i];
                var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
                if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                    if(rowCount <= 1) {
                        alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                        break;
                    }
                    table.deleteRow(i);
                    rowCount--;
                    i--;
                }


            }
            }catch(e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }
```

My problem is that I don't know how and where to write a code to disable the selected option that had been chosen in the first select box in the new added select box.

Is this possible?
Here's [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a_afina/ckoatqp5/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can have a separate table for storing the dataset in hidden mode and maintain the selection state in it. 
Instead of hidden element you can also maintain the state in `javascript` variables.

```
function syncModdelAdd(tableID){
    //  Get the available selections
  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;

  var dataTable = document.getElementById('dataTable');

  for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++){
    var selectedIndex = table.rows[i].cells[1].childNodes[1].selectedIndex;
        dataTable.rows[0].cells[1].childNodes[1].options[selectedIndex].disabled=true;
  }
}

function syncModelDelete(selectedIndex){
  var dataTable = document.getElementById('dataTable');  
    dataTable.rows[0].cells[1].childNodes[1].options[selectedIndex].disabled=false;

  var table = document.getElementById('resultTable');
  var totalRows = table.rows.length;
  table.rows[totalRows-1].cells[1].childNodes[1].options[selectedIndex].disabled=false;
}
```

Fiddle Link : https://jsfiddle.net/2tfacL9k/

Comment: I tried the code and it's helps a lot but there's a problem when I delete the row, the option is still disable. However I'll try to adjust the code by myself and see if it works. Thank you so much.